# Can VS 2013 community edition be installed alongside other VS versions

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to build mobile apps for cross platform, and I came across VS 2013 community edition. I already have VS 2012 and VS 2013 installed (premium version). I read some where that VS 2013 community version if installed requires other VS editions to be uninstalled. 
So is it safe to install VS 2013 community edition along with other VS editions?.

Comment: Premium has all features of the CE, which is basically a Pro. Start your cross platform coding with the Premium Edition.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the Community edition is in the same family as Pro/Premier/Ultimate you cannot install it side-by-side with them.

Source: https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Visual-Studio-2013-Community-Professional-development-for-free

Comment: But it can be installed next to other versions (2010,2012)

Comment: VS 2013 can be installed side by side with previous versions of Visual Studio according to Brian Harry´s Blog post announcing Visual Studio 2013. - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/10/17/visual-studio-2013-rtm-available.aspx

Comment: if the above comment elaborate my answer, let me know and I'll add it to my answer so other will have the whole picture.